# Distribute StageVideo two multiple screens

Tags: actionscript-3, air

i need to play a video on two different screens.
Right now i am using two Videofiles playing on two Stage objects in NativeWindows.
Is it possible to use just one big file and split it to the two screens?

thanks!

Comment: I think that you can do that using your graphics card and not ActionScript.

Comment: ok, i need to say that this is just part of an application ( the background ) and it has much more going on. so i do need it to work in air using actionscript.

Comment: Have you tried to resize the window using x, y, width, height and set it to the size of the 2 monitors?

Comment: Yes I did. But it does not work unfortunately. 
On Fullscreen the Window streches back to the screens bounds.